# element jumps to next line when child added

Tags: css

Can you please tell me
why element id="annex2" junps to the next line when  child id="option_box" addes.
and How can I fix it so that it does not jump when child id="option_box" is added.

Thanks!

```
 `.annex_label {
     width: 100%;
 }
 .annexes { /* container of the annexes */
     margin-top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: fit-content;
 }
 .annex  { /*indivual annex */
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     width: 139px; height: 330px;
 }

 .top_card {
     width: 139px; height: 210px;
 position: relative; 
 z-index: 20;
 }
 .burried1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
 z-index: 10;
 }
 .burried2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 80px;
 z-index: 5;
 }
 .burried3 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 z-index: 0;
 }
 .option_box { 
 margin: 3px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }`



`<div  class="annex_label">Annxes
    <div  class="annexes">
        <div id="annex1" class="annex">
            <div class="top_card"></div>
            <div class="burried1"></div>
            <div class="burried2"></div>
        </div>
        <div  id="annex2" class="annex">
            <div class="top_card">
                <div id="option_box" class="option_box">click me</div>
            </div>
            <div class="burried1"></div>
            <div class="burried2"></div>
       </div>`your text`
       <div  id="annex3" class="annex">
           <div class="top_card"></div>
       </div>
       <div id="annex4" class="annex">
           <div class="top_card"></div>
           <div class="burried1"></div>
           <div class="burried2"></div>
           <div class="burried3"></div>
       </div>`
   </div>
</div>`
```

I have tried using flex

but the burials jumped to other annexes as their position is abolute

Comment: Please add minimal working code snippet that demonstrates your issue. Currently it's impossible to understand the issue.